# Add xml to http redirect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, http-redirect

I have a situation whereby I need to redirect a user from a page on my server to a page on another server. In this redirect I need to also send some xml to the server I am redirecting to. This xml file could be quite long so just sending it in the querystring isn't an option.

I have tried attaching the xml in a header but the header doesn't seem to make it to the other end.

I know how to programmatically create requests to send xml and how to redirect, just not sure how to do both at the same time.

In short, I need the xml to piggy-back on the redirect. This redirect will be done from within an MVC Action.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

I have come up with the following potential solution to my problem. Unfortunately it does utilise two requests which I had hoped to avoid.

Basically I send the xml file as a header of a post request which also contains a session id. This is sent asynchronously.

I then redirect the user, passing the same sessionid in the querystring. This acts as a token to link one request to the other. I just need to wait now and find out if the other party are willing to work using two requests.

I also looked in to using an additional page that I could redirect the user to which could contain Javascript to perform an additional form post to the other server with a form that would contain just a single field containing the xml fragment, but this was excluded as a possibility by my boss (rightly so as it seems like a bit of a hack).

Are there any obvious or non-obvious drawbacks to my proposed method, other than the obvious possibility of a race condition between the 2 requests?

Comment: I *think* what you need to do is send the XML to them and get a token back.  Then you redirect the user to a URL containing that token.  Now, the third party site knows to associate the XML blob with that user.  You see this sort of arrangement in some payment processing systems.

Comment: What's going to make use of this XML, since the client is going to go to the redirected-to resource anyway? Knowing the answer to this may help knowing how to advise further.

Comment: Alternatively you can redirect the user to the third party site with a token in the URL.  You know the token is associated with a particular blob.  The third party site takes the token and requests the blob from you, which you provide.  Now the third party has the user and the XML blob.  Same thing, but the party generating the token is you instead of them.

Comment: @jon The xml payload will be used to generate the content in the page that the user is being redirected to.

Comment: @inuyasha there is a fair amount of processing that needs to be done on the xml blob. Having the other end request it after the user has been redirected will add too much latency. +1 for the idea though.

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect to http://otherServer/handlerPage.aspx?xmlSource=http%3A%2F%2FfirstServer%2FxmlSource.aspx%3FparameterForXml1%3Dfoo%26parameterForXml2%3Dbar

Then at http://otherServer/handlerPage.aspx the xmlSource parameter is http://firstServer/xmlSource.aspx?parameterForXml1=foo&parameterForXml2=bar which can be used to obtain the XML.